# Facing issues while opening a URL in the default browser using Java on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-interface, java-11

I have a simple **Java program** what I want to do is to open a **URL** for *example "https://github.com"* in the default browser on my Operating System in my case, I use **Windows 10**.

Here is what I get while I run the program on **eclipse**:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLh4N.png)

I think there is something wrong with **my code**:

```
package com.main;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;

public class Browser {
    public void displayURL() throws Exception {

        String url = "https://github.com";
        String myOS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        System.out.println("(Your operating system is: " + myOS + ")\n");

        try {
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                System.out.println(" -- Going with Desktop.browse ...");
                Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                desktop.browse(new URI(url));
            } else {
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
                if (myOS.contains("windows 10")) {
                    System.out.println("Hello Windows 10");
                    pb.command("start " + url);
                    pb.start();
                } else if (myOS.contains("mac")) {
                    pb.command("open " + url);
                    pb.start();
                } else if (myOS.contains("nix") || myOS.contains("nux")) {
                    pb.command("xdg-open " + url);
                    pb.start();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Sorry!! I could not launch the browser on your operating system.");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Oops!! Something is wrong. " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I hope to find a solution

Comment: `Desktop.isDesktopSupported()` returns `false`. The subsequent conditions do not cover the case of myOS being `"windows 10"`, you need to add code for that.

Comment: can you provide me an example please

Comment: I'm new in java

Comment: You probably want to use `myOS.startsWith("windows")` instead of the unnecessarily specific condition `myOS.contains("windows 10")`.

Answer (score 0):

Class [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is intended for launching executables.

I don't have access neither to MacOS nor linux so I can't comment on them.

For Windows, `start` is not an executable, it is an internal command of [cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) (just like `dir`). Hence the error message you are getting. Java is looking for an executable named `start` and cannot find one.

On Windows, in order to launch the default Internet browser, you can use [rundll32.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rundll32).

```java
import java.io.IOException;

public class Browser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("rundll32.exe",
                                               "url.dll,OpenURL",
                                               "https://github.com");
        try {
            pb.start();
        }
        catch (IOException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above code it launches [Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge?form=MA13FJ) on the GitHub home page.